# NO_PUBKEY error after the key was successfully added

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` a get the following error:

```
Err:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

I can't rid off this error no matter what I try.

The ways I've tried to resolve the issue:

**1. Adding key manually**

I've googled how to solve the error and it seems that everybody recommends to add missing public key via `apt-key`:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv B53DC80D13EDEF05
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.MRlBtkNXHX/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv B53DC80D13EDEF05
gpg: key B53DC80D13EDEF05: 1 duplicate signature removed
gpg: key B53DC80D13EDEF05: "Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2022-03-07-08_01_01.pub)" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

After executing the commands above, the `NO_PUBKEY` error persist.

**2. Removing repository**

I've looked through the list of repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and I've found `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

I've deleted the file via `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Kubernetes signing key.

   On each server node, use the curl command to download the key, then store it in a safe place (default is `/usr/share/keyrings`):

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes.gpg
   ```
2. Add software repositories.

   Kubernetes is not included in the default repositories. To add the Kubernetes repository to your list, enter the following on each node:

   ```
   echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes.gpg] http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Kubernetes installation tools

   Kubeadm (Kubernetes Admin) is a tool that helps initialize a cluster. It fast-tracks setup by using community-sourced best practices. Kubelet is the work package, which runs on every node and starts containers. The tool gives you command-line access to clusters.

   Execute the following commands (on each server node).

   - Install Kubernetes tools with the command:

     ```
      sudo apt install kubeadm kubelet kubectl
     ```

     Set Kubernetes tools on hold:

     ```
      sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm kubelet kubectl
     ```
   - Verify the installation with `kubeadm version`

<sub>**source:** [How to Install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 20.04](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu)</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "On each node" in the very first step of your answer? I get this error not on my k8s nodes of  my k8s cluster, but on my personal machine.

Comment: The phrase "On each server node" refers to each individual computer that will be part of your Kubernetes cluster. A Kubernetes cluster is a group of computers working together to manage containerized applications. A server node is a an individual computer in the Kubernetes cluster that runs containerized applications. The instructions are telling you to perform certain actions on every computer that will be part of your Kubernetes cluster. This is because Kubernetes relies on multiple computers working together to handle the workload.

Answer (score 7):

In my case nothing worked until I simply used --dearmor to make gpg binary instead of ASCII when downloading the updated key.

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg| gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg --dearmor
```

apt-get update worked after that without errors

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me.

Note the tilde on the end of the filename cloud.google.gpg~ (not a typo)

```
sudo rm -fr /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg~
sudo curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg| sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg --dearmor
```